# GraphQL Connections

Tags: javascript, graphql, graphql-js, relay, express-graphql

I have this relationship btw a user and its memberships. The memberships field is a connection between a user and multiple memberships.

```js
const MembershipType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Membership',
  interfaces: [nodeInterface],

  fields: {
    id: globalIdField(),

    user: {
      type: new GraphQLNonNull(UserType),
      resolve(parent, args, ctx: Context) {
        return ctx.userById.load(parent.user_id);
      },
    },

    role: {
      type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString),
    },

    team: {
      type: GraphQLString,
    },

    createdAt: {
      type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString),
      resolve(parent) {
        return parent.created_at;
      },
    },

    updatedAt: {
      type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString),
      resolve(parent) {
        return parent.updated_at;
      },
    },
  },
});

export default MembershipType;


const UserType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'User',
  interfaces: [nodeInterface],

  fields: {
    id: globalIdField(),

    firstName: {
      type: GraphQLString,
      resolve(parent) {
        return parent.first_name;
      },
    },

    lastName: {
      type: GraphQLString,
      resolve(parent) {
        return parent.last_name;
      },
    },

    email: {
      type: GraphQLString,
      resolve(parent) {
        return parent.email;
      },
    },

    memberships: {
      type: new GraphQLList(MembershipType),
      resolve(parent, args, ctx: Content) {
        return ctx.membershipsByUserId.load(parent.id);
      },
    },

    membershipsCount: {
      type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLInt),
      resolve(parent, args, ctx: Context) {
        return ctx.userMembershipsCount.load(parent.id);
      },
    },
  },
});

export default UserType;
```

The issue here is that I have this error where **user field in MembershipType** causes an error

> Blockquote
>   /Users/nizarayari/Arise/arise-auth/node_modules/graphql/jsutils/invariant.js:19
>       throw new Error(message);
>             ^
>   Error: Expected undefined to be a GraphQL nullable type.
>       at invariant (/Users/nizarayari/Arise/arise-auth/node_modules/graphql/jsutils/invariant.js:19:11)
>       at assertNullableType (/Users/nizarayari/Arise/arise-auth/node_modules/graphql/type/definition.js:261:51)
>       at new GraphQLNonNull (/Users/nizarayari/Arise/arise-auth/node_modules/graphql/type/wrappers.js:79:54)
>       at Object. (/Users/nizarayari/Arise/arise-auth/src/schema/membership/MembershipType.js:25:13)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:624:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:635:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:545:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (module.js:508:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:500:3)
>       at Module.require (module.js:568:17)
>       at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
>       at Object. (/Users/nizarayari/Arise/arise-auth/src/schema/user/UserType.js:19:1)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:624:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:635:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:545:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (module.js:508:12)

Here is my query for user

```js
import UserType from './UserType';
import type Context from '../../Context';

const me = {
  type: UserType,
  resolve(root: any, args: any, ctx: Context) {
    return ctx.user && ctx.userById.load(ctx.user.id);
  },
};

export default {
  me,
};
```

No queries for memberships just mutation

Comment: Seems like `UserType` might be undefined in `type: new GraphQLNonNull(UserType)`.

Comment: Yes it is. But can't find why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are both fields in the same js file? You have `export default` on both Memberships and UserType in what looks like the same js file.

You can only use `export default` on one field in each file.

Once you separate the two fields, since Membership depends on UserType, the trick is to use a function that returns the fields object in Membership

```
const MembershipType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Membership',
  interfaces: [nodeInterface],
  fields: () => ({
    id: globalIdField(),
    ...
  })
});
```

instead of:

```
const MembershipType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Membership',
  interfaces: [nodeInterface],
  fields: {
    id: globalIdField(),
    ...
  }
});
```

Comment: If I am correct, this issue might be what's referred to as circular dependencies. Here's a helpful resource on that topic: http://siawyoung.com/coding/javascript/circular-references-graphql-type-definitions.html

Answer (score 0):

You might need to move `UserType` above `MembershipType` in the file.

```
let Foo = {
  bar: Bar
}

let Bar = 'bar'

console.log(Foo.bar) // undefined

Foo = {
  bar: Bar
}

console.log(Foo.bar) // 'bar'
```

https://repl.it/@tcoughlin3/CumbersomeClassicRat